# Parametric techniques for n-related samples

Tags: repeated-measures

The title is quite self-explanatory - I'd like to know if there's any other parametric technique apart from repeated-measures ANOVA, that can be utilized in order to compare several (more than 2) repeated measures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multilevel/hierarchical linear models can be used for this.  Essentially, each repetition of the measure is clustered within the individual; individuals can then be clustered within other hierarchies.  For me, at least, it's more intuitive than repeated-measures ANOVA.

The canonical text is [Raudenbush and Bryk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/076191904X); I'm also really fond of [Gelman and Hill](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X).  [Here's a tutorial I read some time ago](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.5130&rep=rep1&type=pdf) - you may or may not find the tutorial itself useful (that's so often a matter of personal taste, training and experience), but the bibliography at the end is good.

I should note that Gelman and Hill doesn't have a ton on multilevel models specifically for repeated measures; I can't remember if that's the case or not for Raudenbush and Bryk.

Edit: Found a book I was looking for - [Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis by Singer and Willett](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195152964) has (I believe) an explicit focus on multilevel models for repeated measures.  I haven't had a chance to read very far into it, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: I doubt that anyone is going to top this one. Thanks Matt, great answer!

Comment: Forgotten bonus: unbalanced data are still useful!